# Is there any way to pass multiple parameters to an ajax success function that are echoed in a php page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code :

**edit_menu.php**

```
function update_module(id) {
var check;
 if($("#checkbox1"+id).attr('checked')){
    check=1;
  }
 else{
    check=0;
 }

var name = $('.name_text_module'+id).val();
var displayorder = $('.desc_text_module'+id).val();

$.ajax ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "update_module.php",
    data: "name="+name+"&displayorder="+displayorder+"&id="+id+"&check="+check,

    success: function(msg)
        {
           //In this function I want to send two parameters to the success function
            // somewhat like this 'success: function(msg1,msg2)'
        }       
});
```

}

**update_module.php**

```
session_start(); 
include('../../db.php');

$module=$_GET['name'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
$check=$_GET['check'];
$displayorder=$_GET['displayorder'];

$modulename = str_replace("_"," ",$module);

echo $modulename;
echo $displayorder;

HmsDB::getInstance()->updateModule($id,$modulename,$displayorder,$check);

echo "<script>alert('Updated Successfully');</script> ";
```

I have to send variables $modulename & $displayorder to the success function as two different variables. Is this possible ?
Thanks already :)

Comment: Send your response in JSON format.

Comment: Ohk ! I haven't used JSON yet, maybe this is the begining for it ! will try.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum it up, you can do something like this:

**php file**

```
$data = array();
$displayorder=$_GET['displayorder'];
$modulename = str_replace("_"," ",$module);

$data['displayorder'] = $displayorder;
$data['modulename'] = $modulename;

HmsDB::getInstance()->updateModule($id,$modulename,$displayorder,$check);

echo json_encode($data);
```

**javascript**

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "update_module.php",
    data: "name="+name+"&displayorder="+displayorder+"&id="+id+"&check="+check,

    success: function(msg)
        {
           msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
           alert("Display Order: "+msg.displayorder+"\n Module: "+msg.modulename);
        }       
});
```

More information about [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Note: While using this approach you've to make sure only `$data` is returned/echoed back. If there is anything else added to it (notices, warnings, html etc), the JSON will break and not give you the output.

Comment: Good. You can extend it further. But I'll leave that to you to research and learn